# Как определить какая из данных дат ранняя, а какая поздняя? С++

Tags: c++, дата

Файл data.txt содержит 5 дат:

```
15.11.2016
30.12.1998
23.01.2013
12.12.2012
11.11.2011
```

Как определить какая из них ранняя, а какая поздняя?
Программа считывает даты из файла и выводит их на экран

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() { 

const int n = 5;

    string* dat = new string[n];

    ifstream fin("data.txt", ios_base::in);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        getline(fin, dat[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << dat[i] << endl;
    }

    fin.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

То есть нужно как-то позапоминать со строк числа в переменные дня, месяца, года по отдельности и сравнивать дальше...
Или есть ли какая-то библиотека в С++, с помощью которой можно произвести это сравнение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто сравнить даты - переведите из в вид `YYYYMMDD`, и сравнивайте как `<` или там `>=` - словом, обычные целые числа.

Конечно, можно заполнить структуру `tm` и получить значение `time_t` с помощью функции `mktime`, но для сравнения все это не нужно.

```
char * s = "11.05.2016";
int d,m,y;
if (sscanf(s,"%d.%d.%d",&d,&m,&y) == 3)
{
    int date = y*10000+m*100+d;
    cout << date << endl;
}
```

Можно считывать из потока прямо в переменные, словом, любое преобразование форматированной строки в целые числа...

Comment: string перевести в int вида YYYYMMDD? Напр., 11.11.2011 будет 20111111 Но как переводить?

Comment: Например, простой `sscanf` - см. ответ.

Comment: Да просто переверните строки, и сравнивайте их `strcmp()`

Comment: Перевернуть? А что с точками тогда делать? У меня ж дата таким форматом 11.11.2011

Comment: Точки никак не повлияют.

Comment: @PinkTux *Просто перевернуть* не получится - будут `6102.50.11`, которое явно меньше `7991.40.10` :)

Comment: @Harry, да, что-то затупил :)

Comment: @Harry, big spasiba, ты помог :*

Comment: Есть такой стандарт, ISO8601, очень популярный во всяком JSON'е, и у него есть одно занимательное свойство: сравнение строк в ISO8601 даёт такие же результаты, как и сравнение соответствующих моментов времени (правда, только при условии, что они представлены в одинаковых часовых поясах, но это уже детали). И работает это по точно такому же принципу.

Comment: Так вы же - судя по первому рисунку - переводите только последний - `mass[5]`! Выложите ваш код куда-нибудь типа на http://vpaste.net/ и дайте ссылку, я посмотрю, что и как. И заодно - файл с вашими данными.

Comment: Гляньте тут: http://vpaste.net/S61mN

Comment: Блин!!! Вы же перепутали первое и второе измерения! `char mass[len][datas]` - это `len` строк длиной `datas`!! Замените на `char mass[datas][len];` и все у вас получится...

Comment: http://vpaste.net/ZeJm7

Answer (score 1):

Не изобретайте [велосипед](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13787702/comparing-2-dates-in-c), используйте `std::get_time()` (из стандартной библиотеки chrono) и сравнивайте объекты дат с помощью `<`.

Вы ж не на Си пишите, чтобы извращаться с парсингом строк или `time_t`. Используйте мощь С++11 =)

Comment: Вы получите ту же `struct tm`, о которой говорил я, и как их сравнивать? Опять же, преобразуя во что-то другое...

Comment: Та мне подошел способ перевода в вид YYYYMMDD)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, совершенно не понятно, почему вы выделяет память динамически, когда размер массива у вас является константной.

Если же размер массива может менять в зависимости от числа строк в файле, то лучше использовать стандартный класс `std::vector`.

Вы можете объявить простую структуру, которая будет хранить выделенные значения года, месяца и дня для заданной даты.

Вы также можете сразу же отсортировать вектор по возрастанию дат.

иже показана программа, как это можно сделать. Только вместо входного файла, я в программе использовал поток строк для простоты.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

struct Date
{
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
};

int main() 
{
    std::string s = "15.11.2016\n" "30.12.1998\n";

    std::vector<Date> dates;

    std::istringstream input( s );

    std::string line;

    while ( std::getline( input, line ) )
    {
        Date d = {};
        char c;

        std::istringstream is( line );

        is >> d.day >> c >> d.month >> c >> d.year;

        dates.push_back( d );
    }

    std::sort( dates.begin(), dates.end(),
               []( const Date &d1, const Date &d2 ) 
               { 
                return std::tie( d1.year, d1.month, d1.day ) < 
                       std::tie( d2.year, d2.month, d2.day ); 
               } );

    for ( Date d : dates ) 
    {
        std::cout << d.day << '.' << d.month << '.' << d.year << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
30.12.1998
15.11.2016
```

Чтобы сравнивать даты, хранимые в объектах структуры, вы можете определить оператор `operator <` следующим образом

```
bool operator <( const Date &d1, const Date d2 )
{
    return std::tie( d1.year, d1.month, d1.day ) < 
           std::tie( d2.year, d2.month, d2.day ); 
}
```